# Componente ice:selectInputText quiero agregarle styleClass="form-control"

Tags: html, bootstrap

quiero agregar dicho componente Icefaces 1.8 con styleClass="form-control" de bootstrap me genera un input sin el estilo sobre otro que si contiene el estilo. En los demas Input utilizo en todos form-control. Se les ocurre como puedo hacer para que me genere solamente un input con este estilo? 
Desde ya muchas gracias! Saludos

```html
<ice:selectInputText id="idunidad-no-catalogo-id" 
     rows="15" width="300"
     value="#{handler.selectedText}"
     converter="serializationConverter"
     styleClass="form-control" 
     partialSubmit="true"                          
     textChangeListener="#{handler.textChanged}"
     actionListener="#{handler.submitText}"
     rendered="#{!planAnualHandler.usaCatalogo}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{handler.unidadesItems}" />
   <f:attribute name="zonaEntregaItem" value="#{zonaRow}"/>
</ice:selectInputText>
```

y genera este codigo HTML:

```
<div class="iceSelInpTxt form-control" rows="15" width="300">
   <input autocomplete="off" 
      class="iceSelInpTxtTxt form-controlTxt" 
      id="form:cantidadTable:0:idunidad-no-catalogo-id" 
      name="form:cantidadTable:0:idunidad-no-catalogo-id" 
      onblur="setFocus('');" 
      onfocus="setFocus(this.id);" 
      onmousedown="this.focus();" 
      style="width:300px;" 
      type="text" 
      value="rO0ABXQAAA==">
   <div class="iceSelInpTxtList form-controlList" 
      id="form:cantidadTable:0:idunidad-no-catalogo-id_div" 
      style="display: none;">
   </div>
   <input name="form:cantidadTable:0:idunidad-no-catalogo-id_idx" 
      type="hidden" value="">
</div>
```

Asi se ve:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Eso se debe a que la etiqueta ice:selectInputText no es un input propiamente si no que cuando es compilado y renderizado en HTML crea otros atributos que la clase form-control no reconoce, te recomiendo usar selectores avanzados de css donde hagas referencia desde tu clase hasta el input que necesites por ejemplo .iceSelInpTxt>input:first-child{background:red}

Comment: Funciono muchas gracias! @TheVicShow se te ocurre porque tiene ese valor el input? ya inicialicé la variable selectedText en vacio.

Comment: No sabría decirte, es difícil sin ver corriendo el código pero puedes revisar el método unidadesItems para ver si esta trayendo los valores que necesitas. agrega un break point en el método